# Instantiating Sklearn Models Iteratively

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to create, train, and test sklearn models iteratively:

```
for min_samples_leaf in [1, 2, 3, 5]:
    for min_samples_split in [2, 3, 4, 10]:
        for n_estimators in [200, 500, 1000, 1500]:
                classifier = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, min_samples_leaf=min_samples_leaf, min_samples_split=min_samples_split, n_estimators=n_estimators, random_state=6, n_jobs=4)
                classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
                print(accuracy_score(y_validate, classifier.predict(X_validate)))
```

However, the accuracy score is the same every time that `classifier` is trained and prints a result against a validation set.

My questions are (1) why is this happening? (2) what is the correct way to take this approach?

Edit: It may be relevant to note that I'm also measuring accuracy in other ways as well as the accuracy score, and the results are truly identical with every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're training the last `classifier` variable value, which happens to be the last configuration of the loop.

To solve this scenario I suggest you two approach:

1. run the `classifier.fit()` function right after the `classifier` assignation and store the result into an array/dictionary, in the fashion that suits you best.
2. create an array (`classifiers =[]`) on top of the first loop and append to it every new classifier you configure, latter iterate such list, and fit each classifier.

**Going further**

What you're trying to do is a hyper parameter search, and that's not the most scalable way.

You can take a look into this blog entry for how to properly do it: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-conceptual-explanation-of-bayesian-model-based-hyperparameter-optimization-for-machine-learning-b8172278050f

If you are in a hurry and need to see how to implement hyper parameter tuning right away and need an example, see the notebook of the above blog entry.

https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/hyperparameter-optimization/blob/master/Bayesian%20Hyperparameter%20Optimization%20of%20Gradient%20Boosting%20Machine.ipynb

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I realized that my original question was misleading, because it implied that the iteration process was completed, and then a score was taken. I've updated the question for more clarity. I appreciate the other resources! I'm considering a move to RandomizedSearchCV as well, but I don't understand why my by-hand iteration process isn't working.

Comment: you said that the accuracy is almost the same, probably that's because of the linearity in  the dataset, meaning that few features are determinant for classification. Try using less than 200 estimators (50, 75 and 200?) and let me know if you notice a decrease.

Comment: It's exactly the same, down to the digit, and persists even with 20 estimators.

Comment: For the accuracy score, it prints:
`0.999849110696165
0.999849110696165
0.999849110696165`
etc.

Comment: Odd. In that case, please try another metric such as `roc_auc`, still a common metric for binary classification

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a multi-label classification problem.